# Which elements could possibly commute with a cycle of full length in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

In the symmetric group of degree $n$, which elements could possibly commute with the permutation $\sigma$ given by $\sigma(i) = i+1$ if $i < n$; $\sigma(n) = 1$?

Of course, the permutations $e= \sigma^0$, $\sigma$, ..., $\sigma^{n-1}$ all commute with $\sigma$.

Do any other elements too?

Comment: Yes, but this product is in fact the original cyclic permutation raised to the third power, isn't it?

Comment: @Saaqib: Yes, reflection through the centre is a half turn.

Answer (score 5):

Your $\sigma$ is actually the cycle $(1 2 \dots n)$, an $n$-cycle. The size of conjugacy class of $\sigma$ is equal to the total number of $n$-cycles, which is equal to $\frac{n!}{n}=(n-1)!$. Thus the number of elements which commute with $\sigma$ is equal to $|S_n|/|Cl_{S_n}(\sigma)|=n!/(n-1)!=n$. You have already found $n$ elements which commute with $\sigma$, and thus they are the only element which commute with $\sigma$. (This is actually an elaboration of the hint given by @YACP).

Comment: deibor, How to determine the size the conjugacy class of an element of a non-abelian group? I'm afraid I'm unable to understand the starting part of your argument.

Comment: The size of conjugacy class of an element $\sigma$ is equal to the no of elements of the group which have same cycle structure as $\sigma$. This is true only for symmetric group.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sigma'=\pi\sigma\pi^{-1}$ where $\pi\in S_n$ then $\sigma'(\pi(i))=\pi(i+1)$ ($i+1$ meant modulo $n$, meaning $n+1\equiv 1$); if $\pi$ and $\sigma$ commute then $\sigma'=\sigma$, i.e.  $\pi(i+1)=\pi(i)+1$ (mod $n$), hence $\pi$ is fully determined by $\pi(1)$ and is a power of $\sigma$. So there is nothing else.

Comment: user8268, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The orbit of $\sigma$ consists of all $n$-cycles. How many $n$-cycles are there?

Comment: YACP, I'm sorry, but I'm not getting the hint.